Preprocessors in the BSD and GNU make build systems
Microsoft's nmake build system has a wonderful thing called a preprocessor.
For example, if I write the following in my make file
!IFDEF SOMEMACRO

target1 : dependent1
    command1

terget2 : dependent2
    command2

!IFEND

then none of the targets between the preprocessor directives !IFDEF and !IFEND will not be processed until the macro SOMEMACRO is not defined.
I.e., the command
nmake.exe /l /f MYMakefile target1 target2
will terminate with the message that there are no targets.
However, if the macro is defined before this preprocessor condition in the makefile or on the command line when calling nmake.exe, then the targets will be processed and the commands will be executed, if, of course, the goals are achievable. That is, with this entry
SOMEMACRO = someval
!IFDEF SOMEMACRO

target1 : dependent1
    command1

terget2 : dependent2
    command2

!IFEND

The command nmake.exe /l /f MYMakefile terget2 target1 will be executed.
And with this way of defining the macro
nmake.exe /l /f MYMakefile "SOMEMACRO=someval" target1 target2
command will also be executed.
So here's a question. Is there something similar in UNIX-like systems of make build?
And if there is, it is very desirable to have a universal variant that will work both on real UNIX systems like FreeBSD and so on, and on Linux systems using GNU make.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html

https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+14.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html#DIRECTIVES

nmake shares a heritage with BSD make, but GNU make has diverged to the point where it probably isn't useful or feasible to standardize across versions.

Thanks, guys!
Yes, unfortunately the real UNIX world has proven incompatible with its shadows. Oddly enough, Windows is a bit closer to its roots. There's a reason why it's POSIX certified.
@Shawn, thanks for the links.

have you tried with cmake?
